# HTML/CSS Unknown element stretching page

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on making an old website responsive. http://www.risumfeldt.dk/

When i view it in a viewport below 980px width horizontal scroll is activated and html/body/container stays at 980px.

I've tried forcing a width 200px inline on all elements, but the page is still stretched and i'm at a loss. Is anyone able to identify the problem?

Problem was the table in #fp-boxes. Was testing in Chrome's viewport, and forcing widths didn't change pagewidth without a refresh, which then reset the forced widths to the initial value. Everything worked fine in firefox' vievport.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 I would love to be able to just post a small piece of code containing the problem, however i am unable to identify the element on the page containing the problem.

If i figure out which element is the problem and why, i will happily edit my post with the relevant problem/solution for future reference. I hope this is acceptable.

Comment: Please re-frame the question. I think you meant `Horizontal scrollbar`

Comment: @ManojKumar You're right, i've edited the mistake

Comment: The table that is stretching the page. It's TDs have inline style giving them a width in pixels, and that inline style will overwrite anything else you try to do, so they'll always be 300px, 200px, etc, etc, so when you make the viewport 500px wide, it's going to scroll over because the table is still 800px wide or whatever.

Comment: @Quintile In my viewport right now with some major hacking the table is 200px and td's ~30px, but the problem still persists

Comment: Your responsiveness coding is incorrect. So many mistakes am afraid. You can use `Twitter Bootstrap` to help you get responsiveness.

Comment: I agree the site is really sh**** made, and luckily i'm not responsible. It's an old customer stubborn enough to demand we make his current site responsive instead of getting a new improved site, like we recommended. As a side note, giving the table display:none; doesn't fix the problem either, so i'm assuming that the table isn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

Took a quick look at the site, there are a few problems.

Issue 1 - Shopping Cart has set margin-left which expands the page (style.css line 88)

```
.m-shoppingbasket {
  width: 295px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 739px;
  top: 6px;
  background: #8bbeb7;
}
```

Possible Solution - Remove margin-left and replace with float right and adjust accordingly

Issue 2 - Feature boxes (fp-boxes) contains a table with set widths

```
            <td style="width: 334px; height: 201px;" valign="top">...</td>
            <td style="width: 334px;" valign="top">...</td>
            <td style="width: 334px;" valign="top">...</td>
```

Solution - Remove absolute widths and opt for responsive grid or just set percentages. I would switch away from tables for displaying three boxes side by side all together...

It also appears you've added a media query (style.css line 733)

You can also fix this by creating a responsive image class, so that the featured promos shrink according to the size of the table

```
.img-responsive {
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto
}
```

Issue 3 - Footer text container is set to 1000px width (style.css line 610)

```
.footer-container .footer {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Solution - Remove width

There might a few other problems, but this should get you started.

Comment: the `header` also has fixed width.

Comment: And with `fp-boxes`, the actual issue is the `width` attribute of the images: `<img ... width="334">`. The `td` width doesn't seem to kick in once you remove that attribute or set it to `100%`.

Comment: You're right. Was testing in chromes viewport, and forcing a smaller width on the table, td and img in fp-boxes did not change the overall page width, unless i did a refresh. Which then reset the width to the initial values. Tried using firefox' viewport and it works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width:980px) and (min-width:300px) { 
      #wrapperselector { 
        max-width: 200px; 
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }
}
```

Also, I think your not displaying all your code in issue.

*If your saying you tried forcing all elements to 200px width; you probably did something like;*

```
* {
  width: 200px;
}
```

And that stretches everything so don't do that!